# Why the MCU gets too hot when I plug it in to the USB?

Tags: microcontroller, msp430, texas-instruments

**EDIT1:** There is nothing connected to the board.

**EDIT2:** The board **works** but I don't know why it gets too hot.

I'm testing my new board MSP432P401R LaunchPad Rev 1.0 (black) from Texas Instruments. I've read some of [its datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/msp432p401r.pdf), I've downloaded Energia IDE (it's a copy of the Arduino IDE) and the Code Composer Studio. It's a great board but I'm very surprised because it gets **too hot** when I connect it to the USB port.

Viewing its datasheet in the Features section (page 1) in Operating Characteristics, its voltage range goes from 1.62 to 3.7V. So I think that the USB provides it more than 3.7V but I'm disconcerted because the board has some pins to plug in 5V. It's a board designed to consume less power but it produces a lot of heat, is it not contradictory? Why the MCU gets too hot? Is it damaged?

Thanks anyway

Comment: Can you put some metrics to "too hot"?

Comment: Your datasheet link doesn't work properly...

Comment: This is the Launchpad board? What else do you have it plugged into? Does it enumerate on USB?

Comment: @Tyler I can't measure the temperature but when I say too hot I refer that if you touch the MCU it hurts you. Probably, it gets more than 70ºC

Comment: @pjc50 Yes, it's the Launchpad board. There is nothing connected to the board. I don't know what you refer with your third question.

Comment: Does the PC you've plugged it into report it as a device? (see Device Manager on Windows). If so, it's at least partially working.

Comment: @pjc50 The board works but I don't know why it gets too hot when I plug it in the USB.

Comment: LDO's get hot its a fact of life, dev boards use them because they are cheap. DC to DC converters are more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

The older version of these boards, the "black" variant is known to have issues with overheating. Some guys over on the TI forums did some tests and managed to narrow it down to ESD damage from an overvoltage spike caused by touching C125 near the edge of the board whilst powered on.

You can read more about it here: [Link to TI forums](https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/msp430/f/166/t/490273#)

Comment: I've read the link but it's too technical for me. So, the solution can be to add a capacitor greater than C125? Of course thanks for the info.

Comment: basically: you touched a part, you shocked it (even if you didn't feel a shock, very small shocks can still cause damage). Replacing the part that is getting hot (a voltage regulator) would fix it, but few have the equipment to replace a part like that, and even fewer have the skills.